# Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\Zend_Mime' not found in

Tags: magento-2.1

I put that function on the `transpotbuilder` file in core file , but it has still error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\Zend_Mime' not
>   found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template

```
 public function addAttachment(
    $body,
    $mimeType    = Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
    $disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
    $filename    = null
) {
    $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
    return $this;
}
```

I added this function in core file and try to send attachment email and I got the Above error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add prefix **slash()** before **zend_mime**.

Clear var/generation folder and check,

```
 public function addAttachment(
    $body,
    $mimeType    = \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
    $disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $encoding    = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
    $filename    = null
) {
    $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
    return $this;
}
```

There are not any class related to

**'Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\Zend_Mime.php**

When you use **prefix \ before the class they will route to Mime.php file from path vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mime.php**

Answer (score 1):

```
    class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{

    const TYPE_OCTETSTREAM         = 'application/octet-stream';
    const DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT   = 'attachment';
    const ENCODING_BASE64          = 'base64';

    public function addAttachment(
        $body,
        $mimeType    = self::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
        $disposition = self::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        $encoding    = self::ENCODING_BASE64,
        $filename    = null
    ) {
        $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Use like this then you can resolve this issue.

**Reference:** `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mime.php`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
composer require zendframework/zend-mime
```